# Is there a way of splitting a string based on a drop down selection?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a feature where a user can update hours remaining for any task in the Sprint Backlog  for today or any previous day of the sprint and this needs to be stored in a string for a burndown chart to be created.

I was thinking the easiest way to do this would be to populate a drop down that stores 1 - sprint length total.

The dropdown is populated as follows:-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="selectSprintLength"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:scConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM sc_sprints WHERE scSprintID = @sprint">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="sprint" Name="sprint" 
Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="selectSprintLength">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="sprintLengthDropDown" 
    runat="server"
    AutoPostBack="true"
    DataSource='<%# Enumerable.Range(1, (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "scSprintTotal")) %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I'm stuck on where to go from here. How do I get the user's selection to update a certain place in the string?

Comment: Do you want to split a string or do you want to change a value in a string?  You will want to use the "SelectedIndexChanged" event in the dropdown and then manipulate the string as you want.